# VS 2013 Source Control / Open from Server: Files downloaded in some machine, but does not in other machine

Tags: version-control, tfs

I am opening a full solution (.sln) from TFS using Source Control/Advanced/Open from Server... (VS 2013) The folder associated to the Workspace is empty.

There are some files checked in the TFS within the root folder (or deeper) of the solution what are not part of the of the solution (not added solution items) neither project items in any project.

Now the weird thing:
If I open the solution  (Open from Server) to an empty folder, all these files are downloaded.
However in an other machine if the developer do the same then only that files downloaded where are explicitly part of the solution (solution item in the .sln file) or explicitly part of any project (project item in any .csproj file)

My question is: What can cause this different behavior? I looked for some settings related to this, but with no success.

Thanks in advance

Comment: compare your workspace mappings with the other dev and check whether you are using server or local workspaces

Comment: Bingo, that was it. That was definitely an answer thanks. If you post it as answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compare your workspace mappings with the other dev and check whether you are using server or local workspaces